# Sourcing data into rstudio

Tags: windows, dataframe, rstudio, fread, assign

My mentor and I ran through this code and now I need to find out how to access it from rstudio. Here's what he did:

```
# load first Excel file containing sample IDs, and Iowa Gambling Task scores (latency, total gain); 
# assign input to data frame
>full_rdoc_phenos = data.frame(fread("~/Google Drive/mac_storage/TWAS/rdoc/MergedRDoCData_3.15.18.csv"))
```

Here's what I'm getting:

```
full_rdoc_phenos = data.frame(fread("~/This PC/Desktop/Lab/OneDrive_3_11-17-2019/MergedRDoCData_3.15.18.csv"))
Error in fread("~/This PC/Desktop/Lab/OneDrive_3_11-17-2019/MergedRDoCData_3.15.18.csv") : 
  could not find function "fread"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you load the data.table package with: `library(data.table)`?

Comment: `fread` is probably not in a standard library in R. You probably need to add a `library(something)` to get it to work.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with R Studio or is it just about R?  Please fix subject and tags if appropriate.